# What legal reasons prevent this software vendor from including encryption in their code?

Tags: software

I am working on a software project that requires the use of a setup program. The one my company is using is InnoSetup.

On their [downloads page](https://jrsoftware.org/isdl.php) towards the bottom, under the section titled **Encryption Module** it says:

> "For legal reasons, encryption code is not built into Inno Setup. You must download a separate "encryption module" if you wish to utilize Inno Setup's encryption capabilities..."

What legal reasons are they referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be an anachronism, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_from_the_United_States

Comment: Interesting, I wonder why they can't just get away with it using a disclaimer like openSSL https://www.openssl.org/source/

Comment: @TechnikEmpire, OpenSSL is based out of Europe, so they can tell US export regulators to get stuffed.  For someone based in the US, exporting cryptographic software is a pain, even if you fall under the loose regulations for open-source software.